# C++ unicode latin symbol replace?

Tags: c++11, replace, unicode, ascii

Starting from a text that contains characters like `\u00f9, \u00a0, \u00e8` I would like to replace them with the ascii equivalents `ù, è`, etc.

There is my current implementation, that for some reason every now and then it delete pieces of other words and I don't understand why:

```
pos1 = str2.find("\\u00a0");
pos2 = str2.find("\\u00");
pos3 = str2.find("\\u20");
pos4 = str2.find("\\r\\n");
while (pos1 != std::string::npos)
{
    str2.replace(pos1, 6, "");
    pos1 = str2.find("\\u00a0");
}
while (pos2 != std::string::npos)
{
    str2.replace(pos2, 6, "?");
    pos2 = str2.find("\\u00");
}
while (pos3 != std::string::npos)
{
    str2.replace(pos3, 6, "?");
    pos3 = str2.find("\\u20");
}
while (pos4 != std::string::npos)
{
    str2.replace(pos4, 2, "\n");
    pos4 = str2.find("\\r\\n");
}
```

and there's an example of the text:

```
William Shakespeare \u00e8 stato un drammaturgo e poeta inglese, considerato come il pi\u00f9 importante scrittore in inglese e generalmente ritenuto il pi\u00f9 eminente drammaturgo della cultura occidentale.\u00a0\r\n
```

Comment: The initial values of `pos2`, `pos3` and `pos4` are going to become meaningless after every `while` loop. Also note that those are [extended ASCII](https://www.ascii-code.com/) character

Comment: `ù` and `è` are not ASCII. They could be a locale-specific ASCII superset, or they could be encoded as UTF-8 (changing from single bytes to a multi-byte character), but they're not ASCII.

Comment: @Bob__: To be clear, their isn't just one extended ASCII set, and not all ASCII supersets will even feature these characters. It's why the UTF encodings exist; ASCII supersets are raw binary data that need external metadata to tell you what encoding they're actually using, and are still too limited for fully flexible text representation even then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see is that `\u...` character sequences are always 6 characters, but you are only looking for and replacing 4 characters leaving the other 2 characters in the string.

Also, you are searching for all of the sequences up front, but then you are not taking into account that any replacements the `pos1` loop makes will invalidate `pos2`, `pos3` and `pos4`.  Then any replacements the `pos2` loop makes will invalidate `pos3` and `pos4`. And so on.

I would suggest a completely different parsing strategy:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

...

auto pos = str2.find('\\');
char ch;

while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    if (++pos == str2.size())
        break;

    switch (str2[pos])
    {
        case 'r':
            ch = '\r';
            str2.replace(pos-1, 2, &ch, 1);
            /* or:
            str2.replace(--pos, 2, "");
            */
            break;

        case 'n':
            ch = '\n';
            str2.replace(pos-1, 2, &ch, 1);
            break;

        case 't':
            ch = '\t';
            str2.replace(pos-1, 2, &ch, 1);
            break;

        case '\\':
            ch = '\\';
            str2.replace(pos-1, 2, &ch, 1);
            break;

        case 'u': {
            std::istringstream iss(str2.substr(pos+1, 4));
            unsigned short u;
            if (!(iss >> std::hex >> u)) {
                ch = '?';
            }
            else
            {
                switch (u)
                {
                    case 0x2019:
                        ch = '\'';
                        break;
                    ...
                    default:
                        if (u <= 256)
                            ch = static_cast<char>(u);
                        else
                            ch = '?';
                        break;
                 }
            }
            str2.replace(pos-1, 6, &ch, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    pos = str2.find('\\', pos);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/LK1Q1X)

Comment: Yeah, it work perfectly :D Jesus I'm rusty in C++. Is there any easy implementation that allow me in ```case 'u'``` to replace certain combinations of code like if(substr == "\u2019") replace it with " ' " and not "?" ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, it's perfect :)